# leer código de barras desde el monitor

Tags: c#

Estoy testeando un programa (a) que requiere leer códigos de barra e ingresarlos en una lista (en realidad es un poco más complejo, pero no viene al caso).

Por otro lado tengo un programa (b) que genera los códigos de barra.

Si con el programa (b) imprimo los códigos, eso me implica impresiones, manipular hojas, etc.

He pensado en que el programa (b) los muestre en pantalla y escanearlos desde la misma en el programa (a).

Para esto pondría ambos programas en paralelo en el monitor.

Tengo una computadora Acer Aspire con pantalla de 15".

El código de barras que estoy generando es Code 128.

Por lo que he leído hay un problema con el reflejo, he probado poniendo una hoja A4 delante del monitor, también puse una bolsa de nylon transparente, pero sin éxito. (es lo que tenía a mano)

Tal vez debería cambiar algo en el pictureBox (c#): BackColor, BackgroundImage.

Tal vez dependa del lector de códigos de barra, es un Eclipse ms5145.

Pregunto: Existe alguna forma de leer un código de barras desde la pantalla de un notebook con un lector de códigos de barra ?

Comment: ¿Y cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: @NaCl, Perdón, a veces pienso que lo que quiero surge claramente del relato, ya agregue la pregunta, de a poco iré mejorando

Comment: entiendo que si es un lector con un haz laser puede tener problemas con el reflejo como bien lo mencionas, seria cuestion de probarlo. El tema no es el codigo en si sino la forma en como lee el lector, quizas si el codigo lo llevas a algo asm opaco como un Reader como ser el de Kinder de Amazon o el Sony Reader al ser opaco podrias leer el codigo sin usar papel. Sino la otra es reconocer el codigo mediente el procesamiento directo de la imagen como hace QR con solo sacar una foto

Answer (score 1):

Si, con un código QR, se puede leer desde un monitor sin problemas, si utilizas otros tipos de lectores que no lean QR, no podrás, un EAN13 o un codebar, no serás capaz de leerlo desde un monitor.